# XCUITest - How to access the app device token in XCUITest for triggering the push notification but without setting any UIView in app code?

Tags: xcuitest

**Objective**:
I want to retrieve the app device token for triggering a push notification in XCUITest. To perform the following tests

1. Tapping on the push notification
2. Asserting the push notification texts
3. Taking a screenshot of app's main screen once the push notification is received.

**Limitation**:
I should not create any UIView in the app code for retrieving the device token in my XCUITest.

Please suggest me if there is any other workaround considering the limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered here (same asker, I assume): https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110361